# Eager loading for globalize2 translations

Tags: eager-loading, raise, globalize2

i have 2 models - Issue and Answers (issue has many answers) and both have translations with globalize2. Every time i attempting to load Issue with answers via

```
@issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
@answers = @issue.answers
```

causes loading of translations for each Answer (1 sql query per Answer).

How can i optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
@answers = @issue.answers.all(:include => :translations)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@answers = @issue.answers.all(:include => :answer_translations)
```

Comment: Association named 'answer_translations' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?